# Rundeck ansible inventory: static instead of dynamic

Tags: rundeck

Deployed Rundeck (rundeck/rundeck:4.2.0) importing and discovering my inventory using Ansible Resource Model Source. Having 300 nodes, out of which statistically ~150 are accessible/online, the rest is offline (IOT devices). All working fine.

My challenge is when creating jobs i can assign only those nodes which are online, while i wanted to assign ALL nodes (including those offline) and keep retrying the job for the failed ones only. Only this way i could track the completeness of my deployment. Ideally i would love rundeck to be intelligent enough to automatically deploy the job as soon as my node goes back online.

Any ideas/hints how to achieve that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [health checks](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/healthchecks.html#health-checks-enterprise) feature (only available on PagerDuty Process Automation On-Prem, formerly "Rundeck Enterprise"), in that way you can use a node filter only for "healthy" (up) nodes.

Using this approach (e.g: configuring a command health check against all nodes) you can dispatch your jobs only for "up" nodes (from a global set of nodes), this is possible using the `.*` as node filter and `!healthcheck:status: HEALTHY` as exclude node filter. If any "offline" node "turns on", the filter/exclude filter should work automatically.

On Ansible/Rundeck integration it works using the following environment [variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#host-key-checking): `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False` or using `host_key_checking=false` on the `ansible.cfg` file (at `[defaults]` section).

In that way, you can see all ansible hosts in your Rundeck nodes, and your commands/jobs should be dispatched only for online nodes, if any "offline" node changes their status, the filter should work.

Comment: I am not sure how it suppose to solve my problem. With Health Check i can exclude unhealthy nodes and i want something opposite: ALL the nodes (including unhealthy/inaccessible). So Health Check feature is not helping at all - right ? With ansible host_key_checking it's just to avoid host key checks.... So not related. Again i want effectively rundeck to be smart enough to deploy my playbooks to all the nodes including the ones which are currently down (but will come up soon). Currently i have to constantly track which nodes are up and down and reapply many times the same playbook manually....

Comment: I updated my answer by explaining these approaches. Regards.